# nested categories in Django and usage in template

Tags: django

I followed some instructions given by stackoverflow's answer for nested categories(
by making the category model reference itself in the field called "parent"),

but while implementing it, I came across the template tag problems where I can't really iterate the object since the error message says I can't.

I tried to avoid this problem by trying using {% for i in c.c_set.all %}(where c stands for the for iterator in my template for loop) but just in vain.
How can I loop through the nested categories in my html template using Django? thank you so much for your answer in advance!

###It's my models.py's Category model.

```
class Category(models.Model):

    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', default=None, null=True, blank=True, related_name='nested_category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nesting_level = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=60)
    
    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name




##This is my context_processors.py's function that returns "Category" querysets. 
    def categories(request):
        Category = Category.objects.all()
        
        return {
            
            'Category':Category,
            
        }

###This is my base.html's nav bar tags. 
    <nav>
        <ul>{% for c in Category %}
            <li><a href="{{c.get_absolute_url}}">{{c.nesting_level}}{{c}}</a>
    
                <ul>
                  {% for i in c %}
    
                     <li><a href = "#">{{ i.name}}</a></li>
                
                  {% endfor %}
               </ul>
            </li>   
            
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Category.parent` field has `related_name='nested_category'`. You can use this to get a list of all "child" categories:

```html
{% for i in c.nested_category.all %}
<li><a href="#">{{ i.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the [backwards related objects section of the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects).